# $(2x-5y+3)dx=(2x+4y-6)dy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

This is not a new question. Sorry to revive it, but I cannot find another way because it seems that the original question disappeared (It's not me who posted the original question).

Someone (I don't remember who) asked about solving the ODE :
$$(2x-5y+3)dx=(2x+4y-6)dy$$
Yesterday, I gave an answer to this question, but there was a mistake in it. At this time I had not enough time to make the correction and to rewrite it. So I deleted my answer.

Today, as I wanted to post my corrected answer, I cannot find where the original question as gone.

Since I suppose that the unusual method used in my answer would interest some readers, I post the problem as a new question and the answer will be immediately posted in the answer section.

This procedure was suggested by Max in order to keeps it off the unanswered queue.

Comment: You're the victim of a homework bandit.  He posted the problem.  Stole the answer and then deleted the question before his teacher saw it.

Comment: Sounds funny but if I were a teacher I wouldn't go online to see if at least one of my students do that. how could I identify him ? Sounds like a lot of investment to do it for every single problem , besides he seems keen on learning to go and search for a solution , and so on.

Comment: Hi Goddard ! I like your joke. But the so called "bandit" raised an interesting problem anyways. He gave the opportunity to show a method of solving easier (on my opinion) that the usual ones. Thanks to the bandit !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

The solution is expressed on the form of an implicit equation. If one want the explicit solution $y(x)$ one have to solve the cubic equation for $y$. Of course, it is possible, but tiresome.

Note that the method used above is somehow related to what is sometimes done in the "method of characteristics" for solving PDE.

In addition : CHECKING THE RESULT.

The total derivative of $(x-4y+3)(2x+y-3)^2=C$ is :

$\left( (2x+3y-3)^2+4(x-4y+3)(2x+y-3)\right)dx+\left( -4(2x+y-3)^2+2(x-4y+3)(2x+y-3)\right)dy=0$

After simplification : $3(2x+y-3)\left( (2x-5y+3)dx-(2x+4y-6)dy\right)=0$
$$(2x-5y+3)dx=(2x+4y-6)dy$$
We recover exactly the original ODE. Thus the result $(x-4y+3)(2x+y-3)^2=C$ is correct.

Comment: @Anonymous : Well, would you mind show your calculus.

Comment: lol, sorry I double checked, yes I ended up with the same result, so this should be fine it agrees with my result. (silly arithmetic mistake)

Answer (score 3):

$$(2x−5y+3)dx=(2x+4y−6)dy$$
$$(2x−5y+3)dx+(6-2x-4y)dy=0$$

$$\frac{b_2}{b_1}=\frac{4}{5}$$
$$\frac{a_2}{a_1}=\frac{-2}{2}=-1$$

Notice that $$\frac{a_2}{a_1} \neq \frac{b_2}{b_1}$$

Suppose that $(h,k)$ is a solution then we can write them as

$$2h-5k+3=0 $$
$$2h+4k-6=0$$

Solving $k=-1$,$h=1$

Then with transformation

$$x=X+h$$

$$y=Y+k$$

Our result will be

$$x=X+1$$

$$y=Y+1$$

$$dx=dX$$

$$dy=dY$$

$$(2(X+1)-5(Y+1)+3)dX+(6-2(X+1)-4(Y+1))dY=0$$

$$(2X-5Y)dX+(-2X-4Y)dY=0$$

$$\frac{dY}{dX}=\frac{2X-5Y}{2X+4Y}$$

Notice that this is a homogeneous linear equation then, with transformation $Y=vX$ $\frac{dY}{dX}=v+X\frac{dv}{dX}$

$$v+X\frac{dv}{dX}=\frac{2-5v}{2+4v}$$

$$X\frac{dv}{dX}=\frac{2-5v-2v-4v^2}{2+4v}$$

$$X\frac{dv}{dX}+\frac{4v^2+7v-2}{2+4v}=0$$

$$\frac{dX}{X}+\frac{2+4v}{4v^2+7v-2}dv=0$$

By method of partial fractions we have

$$\frac{2+4v}{(4v^2+7v-2)}=\frac{A}{v+2}+\frac{B}{4v-1}$$

Solving we have

$$\int \frac{6}{9(v+2)}+\frac{4}{3(4v-1)}dv= -\int \frac{dX}{X}$$

$$\ln|(v+2)^2(4v-1)|=-\ln|X^3|+c$$

$$ln\frac{(2x+y-3)^2(4y-x-3)(x-1^3)}{(x-1)^3}=c$$

$$(2x+y-3)^2(4y-x-3)=C$$

Saw this. Couldn't resist answering.